# Undefined variable $respond

Tags: php, api

This is an API. When Phone number duplication enter it gives error
Undefined variable: "$respond ".I don't know why this error occur.

```
<?php
    
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    include'../admin/includes/connection.php';
    $msg = '';
    if (isset($_GET['phone']) && isset($_GET['password'])) {
    
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['name']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['password']);
        $about = $_GET['about'];
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['phone']);
        $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['speciality']);
    //                $tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['tags']);
        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['city']);
        $area = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['area']);
        $whatsapp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['whatsapp']);
        $fb_link = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['fb_link']);
        $default_sort_id = 50;
    //                $image = 'img/avatardefault.png';
        $verification_status = 0;
    
    //    $db->check_public_email($con, $email);
    
        $dup = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `phone` FROM `public_users` WHERE `phone` = '" . $phone . "'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($dup) > 0) {
            $msg = 'This Phone Number address already exist !';
        } else {
            if (empty($phone) || empty($password) || empty($city) || empty($name)) {
                $msg = "Phone, City, Category, Name & Category are required.";
            } elseif (strlen($password) < 5) {
                $msg = "Your password should be at least 6 characters long.";
            } else {
                if (isset($_FILES['profileImage']) && $_FILES['profileImage']['size'] > 0) {
    
                    $target_dir = "uploads/";
                    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["profileImage"]["name"]);
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    
                    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["profileImage"]["tmp_name"]);
                    if ($check !== false) {
                        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                        $uploadOk = 1;
                    } else {
                        echo "File is not an image.";
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                    }
    
    // Check file size
                    if ($_FILES["profileImage"]["size"] > 500000) {
                        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                    }
                    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
                    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
                    } else {
                        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profileImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    //query
                            $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `public_users`  SET `name` = '" . $name . "', `email` = '" . $email . "',`password` = '" . $password . "',`phone` = '" . $phone . "', `speciality` = '" . $category . "',`tags` = '" . $category . "', `city` = '" . $city . "',`area` = '" . $area . "',`about` = '" . $about . "',`image` = '" . $target_file . "',`verification_status` = '" . $verification_status . "',`fb_link` = '" . $fb_link . "',`whatsapp` = '" . $whatsapp . "',`sort_id` = '" . $default_sort_id . "' ");
    //                                    echo "The file " . htmlspecialchars(basename($_FILES["profileImage"]["name"])) . " has been uploaded.";
                            if (!$query) {
                                $msg = "Your request can't be completed at the moment, please contact the admin support.";
                            } else {
                                $msg = 'True';
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                        }
                    }
                    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con) . '';
                    $respond['message'] = $msg;
    
                    $respond['user'] = array('id' => $last_id, 'sort_id' => $default_sort_id, 'verification_status' => $verification_status, 'name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'image' => $target_file, 'phone' => $phone, 'city' => $city, 'area' => $area, 'speciality' => $category, 'whatsapp' => $whatsapp, 'fb_link' => $fb_link, 'about' => $about);
                } else {
                    $image = 'img/avatardefault.png';
                    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `public_users`  SET `name` = '" . $name . "', `email` = '" . $email . "',`password` = '" . $password . "',`phone` = '" . $phone . "', `speciality` = '" . $category . "',`tags` = '" . $category . "', `city` = '" . $city . "',`area` = '" . $area . "',`about` = '" . $about . "',`image` = '" . $image . "',`verification_status` = '" . $verification_status . "',`fb_link` = '" . $fb_link . "',`whatsapp` = '" . $whatsapp . "',`sort_id` = '" . $default_sort_id . "' ");
                    if (!$query) {
                        $msg = "Your request can't be completed at the moment, please contact the admin support.";
                    } else {
                        $msg = 'True';
                    }
                    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con) . '';
                    $respond['message'] = $msg;
    
                    $respond['user'] = array('id' => $last_id, 'sort_id' => $default_sort_id, 'verification_status' => $verification_status, 'name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'image' => 'https://bingo-agency.com/mrworker/' . $image, 'phone' => $phone, 'city' => $city, 'area' => $area, 'speciality' => $category, 'whatsapp' => $whatsapp, 'fb_link' => $fb_link, 'about' => $about);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
    
        $respond["message"] = $msg;
    }
    echo json_encode($respond);//Show me error at this line.//
    ?>
```

while I enter new record it have not show error, But if I enter same phone number as already exist it will show error.  It show me error Undefined variable: "$respond".I don't know why this error occur.

Please help me!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection and is not easy to read but it looks like when the code checks for duplicate email `if (mysqli_num_rows($dup) > 0) {` it then leaves the logic flow and tries to output the json_encoded variable - try declaring `$respond` at the top of the script

Comment: As error said you have to define $respond above like: `$respond = array();`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is undefined that's why you see this error. In your code you have the first if/else:

```
   if (isset($_GET['phone']) && isset($_GET['password'])) {
```

And as a fallback you define the `$respond` variable in your else statement;

Coming to your question though your if that checks if the phone numbers exists sets correctly the variable `$msg` but does not set it in the `$respond` array.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($dup) > 0) {
            $msg = 'This Phone Number address already exist !';
        }
```

This if causes the error because all the other else statements set the variable correct. An easy solution is:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($dup) > 0) {
            $respond['message'] = 'This Phone Number address already exist !';
        }
```